# How to decide the interpreter type in javascript script?

Tags: javascript

In python, this is a self-contained unit test skill:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # blabla
```

If I want to use javascript shell, eg. js/gjs/v8, to write a module, how to code in a similar way. That is, how can I decide if the interpreter is shell or browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to be more specific about what exactly you're trying to do, but a typical test is:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined")
```

which tests for the global window object in a a browser that will not be present in a non-browser environment.

Comment: Enough for me, although I want to get the exact interpreter type in script.